# disable all auto-corrections, mistyping correction, and spellchecking in all microsoft applications

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, skype-for-business

Microsoft applications have by default a lot of auto-corrections, spellchecking, etc enabled. Those are sometimes difficult to find (as it changes with each versions, and it is sometimes hidden behind 2 completely different submenus in the options, or sometimes [skype] un-modifyable).

Is there some easy way to deactivate **all** (or most) of those default auto-corrections in Word+Excel+OneNotes(+skype+...), using a script or an utility (or some hidden (powershell?) command?). That way we could communicate this script/utility to all of our (100+) users so that all of them default to a sane environment that won't modify command-line commands by default, and allow communicating command-lines without having them changed (and often borked) on-the-fly.

(My work uses windows for inter-communications, and most of us are unix users that need to communicate commands to be typed "as is", which some tools will instantly modify (exemple of common annoyances: change spaces to non-breaking spaces, that unix then don't recognise as a separator. Transform parts of a command into smileys. Add caps. renumber things. etc)

This has several harmful effects, such as modifying the commands in unpredictable ways [the ticketing system is on windows and the only way to store several commands is by inserting word documents into it ... those commands can be modified in very weird ways [some spaces, when pasted on the remote machine, become ".", etc]. The chat system is skype-for-enterprise (... you don't want to use it if you can avoid it!) that defaults to : force us to send 1 single line before sending multiple ones, and changes also some things on-the-fly (most ofen: changes part of command lines into smileys... making them unreadable for the remote person). etc.

Comment: Did you check Group policy settings for Microsoft Office?